# Rendering component in order in React

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have two components. component **A** and component **B**. I want to render component **B** after component **A** is fully rendered. I used `useEffect` and `uselayoutEffect` hooks, but those didn't help me. What's your solution?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "after component A is fully rendered"? All components are fully rendered at the same time. Images might take time for the `src` to be fulfilled, is this what component B is waiting on?

Comment: As you say all components are rendered at the same time. I want to render a component after all other components rendered. Or for more clarifying I want to render a component after all the DOM rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Render component **A** with **uselayoutEffect** and component **B** with

```
useEffect(() => {}, [])
```

I specifically prefer **React Lazy Loading** components

Answer (score 0):

The following example is working using `useEffect`. Once `<App />` is rendered, that means `<ComponentA />` is rendered because it is one of its children, so we can use `useEffect` to update the state and render `<ComponentB />`:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

function ComponentA() {
  return <div>A</div>
}

function ComponentB() {
  return <div>B</div>
}

function App() {
  const [componentALoaded, setComponentALoaded] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    setCompALoaded(true)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentA />
      {componentALoaded && <ComponentB />}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

However, it may not be very efficient if you want to do this with a lot of components.